# How to put figures side by side

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

Im trying to put the following 2 figures side by side. For some reason the subfigure and minipage methods are not working. Any sugestions ?

```
\begin{figure}\label{ModelI}
\centering
\serblock
{\parblock{\parblock{\block{$X_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i2}$}}}{\parblock{\block{$X_{i3}$}}{\block{$X_{i4}$}}}}
{\parblock{\parblock{\block{$Y_{i1}$}}{\block{$Y_{i2}$}}}{\parblock{\block{$Y_{i3}$}}{\block{$Y_{i4}$}}}}
\caption{Parallel-Series Model}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\parblock
{\serblock{\serblock{\block{$X_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i2}$}}}{\serblock{\block{$Y_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i3}$}}}}
{\serblock{\serblock{\block{$X_{i4}$}}{\block{$Y_{i2}$}}}{\serblock{\block{$Y_{i3}$}}{\block{$Y_{i4}$}}}}
\caption{Series-Parallel Model}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hello ! Please provide a minimal working example in order for us to help

Comment: You could try using the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package.

Comment: How/where are the macros `\serblock`, `\parblock`, and `\block` defined?

Comment: Put all in the *same* `figure` environment and avoid blank lines *completely*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two side-by-side figures, each with its own `\caption`, you need to encase them in `minipage` environments and make sure not to leave blank lines between the `minipage` environments -- blank lines trigger paragraph breaks.

Note that you need to place any `\label` directives *after* the `\caption` directives. Otherwise, you won't be able to cross-reference the figures correctly -- at least not using LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\serblock
{\parblock{\parblock{\block{$X_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i2}$}}}{\parblock{\block{$X_{i3}$}}{\block{$X_{i4}$}}}}
{\parblock{\parblock{\block{$Y_{i1}$}}{\block{$Y_{i2}$}}}{\parblock{\block{$Y_{i3}$}}{\block{$Y_{i4}$}}}}
\caption{Parallel-Series Model}\label{fig:ModelI-PS}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\parblock
{\serblock{\serblock{\block{$X_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i2}$}}}{\serblock{\block{$Y_{i1}$}}{\block{$X_{i3}$}}}}
{\serblock{\serblock{\block{$X_{i4}$}}{\block{$Y_{i2}$}}}{\serblock{\block{$Y_{i3}$}}{\block{$Y_{i4}$}}}}
\caption{Series-Parallel Model}\label{fig:ModelI-SP}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

PS I have no idea how or where `\serblock` is defined. That's why I didn't post a standalone compilable answer.